# Singleton HSQLDB database through tests

Tags: java, maven, junit, hsqldb

Is there anyway to instantiate a singleton HSQLDB database which will live from the first test until the last test finishes in a Maven project?

Actually, my HSQLDB is created in a static class that is been loaded for each test class.

Java 1.7.0_17
JUnit 4.11
HSQLDB 2.2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `mem:` or `file:` database will preserve the database between tests. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_app_dev_testing for details and more options.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to do this is to run a background thread that instantiates your HSQLDB instance. You can [use the mvn ant task](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/examples/mvn.html) to fork off a java process during the appropriate build step ("test", or "verify", usually).

I think that you need your HSQLDB instance running in a separate thread because the surefire plugin will parallel-ize tests.